# POST request not work. Error: Failed to load response data: No content available for preflight request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, backend

I'm trying to make a post request from my client side to the back-end, however, even with the new movie hardcoded, I keep getting an error that something has failed to load the response data.

Code for front-end below :

```
//Fetch request to create a movie
createMovieButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const movie = {name: 'Movie 100', genre: 'Action'}
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/movies', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Tpye': 'application/json'
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify(movie)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
})

//Fetching the data from the backend
async function getMovies() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/movies')
    const movies = await response.json()
    console.log(movies)
}

getMovies()
```

Code from the back-end below:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

//Creating 'database' of movies
const movies = [
    {
        name: 'Batman',
        genre: 'Action',
        year: 2020
    },
    {
        name: 'Spiderman',
        genre: 'Action',
        year: 2021
    },
    {
        name: 'Ant Man',
        genre: 'Action',
        year: 2022
    },
    {
        name: 'Elf',
        genre: 'Comedy',
        year: 2010
    }
]

//Use cors as middleware
app.use(cors())
//Tell the server how to parse JSON body
app.use(express.json())

//Add new movie
//req.body is the body being sent by the client
app.post('/movies', (req, res, next) => {
    const movie = req.body
    movies.push(movie)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json(movie)
})

//Creating an endpoint to return all movies
app.get('/movies', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(movies)
})

//Getting different genres using : ..... Dynamic Param
app.get('/movies/:genre', (req, res, next) => {
    const genre = req.params.genre
    const filteredMovies = movies.filter(movie => {
        return movie.genre.toLocaleLowerCase() == genre.toLocaleLowerCase()
    })
    res.json(filteredMovies)
})

//======================================================= Seperate 
app.get('/movies/:genre/:year', (req, res, next) => {
    const genre = req.params.genre 
    const year = req.params.year
    res.send(`The genre is ${genre} and the year is ${year}`)
})

// Starting my server
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server is running...")
})
```

The server is running, I've restarted it several times and have tried several things out, but I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Fetch request to create a movie
createMovieButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const movie = {name: 'Movie 100', genre: 'Action'}
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/movies', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify(movie)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
})
```

// copy paste this and tell me the result

Comment: Worked! What did you do differently?

Comment: there was a spelling mistake in your code. "Content-Tpye" =>"Content-Type". and viola